# Cannot delete file but writers are closed

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter

This is my code writing in a file..

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( fileTAG, true );
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter( fos, strFileEncoding );
buf = new BufferedWriter( osw );
buf.write( strTagStream );
buf.newLine();
buf.flush();
if ( buf != null )
{
    buf.close();
}
if ( osw != null )
{
    osw.close();
}
if ( fos != null )
{
    fos.close();
}
```

This is my code first deleting the files and afterwards deleting the directory:

```
File[] arrFiles = fileTagpath.listFiles();
for ( File fileCurrentFile : arrFiles )
{
    if ( !fileCurrentFile.delete() )
    {
        String strMessage = "File <" + fileCurrentFile.getAbsolutePath() + "> has not been deleted.";
        System.out.println( strMessage );
        fail( strMessage );
    }
}
if ( !fileTagpath.delete() )
{
    String strMessage = "Directory <" + fileTagpath.getAbsolutePath() + "> has not been deleted.";
    System.out.println( strMessage );
    fail( strMessage );
}
```

It fails with the message that the file has not been deleted. The output shows the right file and the right directory. If I copy the path to my explorer window I get to the right file. The files path is under

`C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tag`

What's my mistake?

Comment: Change your path like this : C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tag

Comment: `buf` cannot possibly be `null`  at the point you are testing it, and neither can `osw` or `fos`. None of the `close()` calls after `buf.close()` are necessary, and neither is `buf.flush()`. Don't write pointless code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In java if you want to use backslash. Try like this

Your path: **C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tag**

but, you have to always double backslash follow below:

**C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tag**

Comment: @Ganymed If the code you have posted really does create the files you are deleting, and as you are deriving the path names from `File.listFiles()`, I cannot see how this can possibly solve your problem. Unless for some unstated reason `fileTag` is not derived from fileTAGpath`.